# Cant get value from xpath

Tags: python, web-scraping

The code below. Is supposed to return the value "INDICES" instead it returns blank? I Have seen it work on other sites but seems to fail here. All attempts below return blank

```
import requests
from lxml import html

pageContent=requests.get('https://finviz.com/futures.ashx')
tree = html.fromstring(pageContent.content)
Indicies = tree.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "tile_header is-indices")]//*')
Indicies = tree.xpath('//*[@id="futures"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/a[1]/div[1]/text()')
Indicies = tree.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/a[1]/div[1]')
print([e.text_content() for e in tree.xpath('//div[@class="tile_header is-indices" and @style]')])
Indicies = tree.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'tile_header is-indices')]//*")
Indicies = tree.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'tile_header is-indices')]//*")
```

```
var groups = [{"ticker":"INDICES","label":"Indices","contracts":[{"label":"DJIA","ticker":"YM","cot":"124601,124603"}
```

Comment: Have you inspected the content you get back when calling `requests.get`? Nothing there has class `title_header` or `is-indices`. It's likely that the content you're looking for is generated using Javascript, so you're not going to be able to fetch it with `requests`.

Comment: How can I view content every time  I try to print to screen I get that its an element that is a good point didnt think about that

Comment: Well, you can write the value of `pageContent.text` to a file. Or you could just run `curl -o output.html https://finviz.com/futures.ashx`.

Comment: You hit the nail right o the head. The html file come back differently

Comment: The data comes back like illustrated not in the second code box. What do you think is best method to pull data looks more organized.

Comment: What is your expected output? Nowhere in your post I could find you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What's going on?

The page you're trying to scrape has content displayed after executing javascript code (that's the difference you can find between the page you got with curl and the page inspected in your browser), so before using lxml to find what you want you need somethig to help you render javascript.

#### Entering selenium

Selenium will help you in this task. It's an automation for (web)broswers, which means you will need an addon called webdriver (there are several to pick: gecko, chrome, opera, etc.) that can be downloaded with your operating system package manager or manually download them, add them to your PATH or use `executable_path="location\to\geckodriver.exe"` when invoking the webdriver.

Now, how will it look in your code (using chrome as the webdriver)?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from lxml import html
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://finviz.com/futures.ashx')

tree = html.fromstring(driver.page_source)
Indicies = tree.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "tile_header is-indices")]//*')
Indicies = tree.xpath('//*[@id="futures"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/a[1]/div[1]/text()')
Indicies = tree.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/a[1]/div[1]')
print([e.text_content() for e in tree.xpath('//div[@class="tile_header is-indices" and @style]')])
Indicies = tree.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'tile_header is-indices')]//*")
Indicies = tree.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'tile_header is-indices')]//*")

driver.quit()
```

Now you can give some options so it can run silent (--log-level=3), headless (--headless), and more, and the argument itself will depend on the webdriver you use.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options.add_argument("--add-first-thing")
chrome_options.add_argument("--add-second-thing")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

As you can see, Selenium will help you render your page, then you can parse it will lxml, Beautiful Soup, or Selenium itself.

Comment: Thank you. After your recommendation These lines worked

Comment: Indicies = tree.xpath('//*[@id="futures"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/a[1]/div[1]/text()')
Indicies = tree.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/a[1]/div[1]/text()')
print([e.text_content() for e in tree.xpath('//div[@class="tile_header is-indices" and @style]')])

Comment: Not sure how implement second code script but I will have to research. Thanks again!